# RxJava Filter is ignored

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, rx-java2

In my class `Activity` I create a  `Fragment`. To detect if fragment is ready I have a boolen flag `isInitialized` in my fragment. Now I want to run some code in my activity and for that I have to ensure that fragment is ready and the `isInitialized` is true. Now I wrote some RxJava Code to react  on the change of the variable in my `Activity`

```
Observable.just(fragment.isInitialized)
            .filter { _ -> true }
            .subscribe {  load() }
```

If I run my app the method load is allways called even if `isInitialized` is false. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: If `isInitialized` is a field, you can't react to changes to it like that. Use `BehaviorSubject<Boolean> isInitialized`

Comment: Ah ok. That make sense. Can you please post a code example. I'm very new in this topic.

Comment: change boolean to BehaviorSubject<Boolean>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `isInitialized` is a basic field, you can't react to changes to it like that. Use `BehaviorSubject<Boolean>` instead

In your fragment:

```
BehaviorSubject<Boolean> isInitialized = BehaviorSubject.create();
```

Somewhere in your initialization code:

```
isInitialized.onNext(true);
```

In your loading code:

```
fragment.isInitialized
        .filter { _ -> true }
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .doOnNext { load() }
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe { /* loaded */ }
```

Comment: This is awsome. Work like a charme. Thank you very much!

Comment: is the filter really necessary, the subject is their just to push an event, the value  has no consequence, especially as all work in done in the side effect operator.

Comment: Probably not really necessary, unless the OP wants turning into `false` to mean something else.

Comment: Why this not work if I set the filter to false

`fragment.isInitialized
        .filter { _ -> false }
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .doOnNext { load() }
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe { /* loaded */ }`

Comment: Suppose I want do some stuff if the Fragment is destroyed, so I set `fragment.isInitialized` to false and react to it in my `Activity`

Comment: Do you understand the purpose of the [`filter` operator](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#filter-io.reactivex.functions.Predicate-)? "predicate - a function that evaluates each item emitted by the source ObservableSource, returning true if it passes the filter". You return false, therefore...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming isInitialized is a boolean you need to filter on the value. Currently you're returning true for every condition.

```
filter { it }
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I've changed my code to `Observable.just(fragment.isInitialized)
            .filter { it }
            .subscribe {  load() }`

But now the method is never called even if the variable `isInitialized` is true

Comment: Observable.just will emit the value of isInitialized when called - if this is false it will never emit. You probably want isInitialized to be an observable value if you want to react when the value changes.

Comment: Yes this exactly what I need. How can I implement this with RxJava?

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to use a subject, e.g. http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html - you would then call onNext on the subject to emit the new value when it changes.